# What are the possibilities in React Native?

Tags: react-native

What are the possibilities in react native when i consider developing a cross platform mobile app with the following options,

1. code reusability
2. custom plugin integration (any native SDK both iOS and Android)
3. apple/android pay integration
4. GPS, BLE integration
5. Full native API integration

In my point of view, all could be possible.

Please share your valuable experience before making a decision.